# What is the difference between the persist() and put() methods in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I am confused about the difference (if any) between the `persist()` method from `javax.persistence.EntityManager;` and the `put()` method from 
`com.google.appengine.api.datastore`.I know both methods are used to store entities in the datastore for example:

```
 EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
 em.persist(entity);
```

and

```
 DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
 datastore.put(entity);
```

What's the difference between the two, and which method is the best for storing entities? I have searched for an answer but what i find are all vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two completely different APIs. The first is JPA (a standard). The latter is GAE proprietary datastore API. This is not the site for asking which is best since that leads to opinionated responses; suggest you read the Google docs on those APIs and decide

Comment: Thanks.As the edit shows, I was going to ask which was was the best for storing entities.